# Inequality between normed vectors

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x,y$ be two vectors of an normed vector space $E$. Prove that
>   $$\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|\leq2\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|}$$

Any hint/help?

Comment: Hint: do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: First multiply the whole thing by $\|x\|$ to get an equivalent inequality. Then prove this inequality by inserting $-y+y$ and the usage of both the usual triangle inequality $\|u+v\|\le\|u\|+\|v\|$ and the inverse one: $|\|u\|-\|v\||\le\|u-v\|$.

Answer (score 2):

$\|{x\over {\|x\|}}-{y\over {\|y\|}}
\|\leq \|{x\over {\|x\|}}-{y\over {\|x\|}}\|+\|{y\over {\|x\|}}-{y\over {\|y\|}}\|$

$\|{y\over {\|x\|}}-{y\over {\|y\|}}\|$=

$\|y\||({{\|x\|-\|y\|}\over{\|x\|\|y\|}})||=|{{\|x|-\|y\|}\over{\|x\|}}|\leq {{\|x\|-\|y\|}\over{\|x\|}}.$